# Why is string sorted in alphabetic order?

Tags: python

This is from Leetcode 804: Unique Morse Code Words. I am wondering why my code gives the right Morse code but it is sorted in alphabetic order which is not on purpose. Any contribution is appreciated.

Input:

```
words = ["gin", "zen", "gig", "msg"]
```

code:

```
class Solution:
    def uniqueMorseRepresentations(self, words: List[str]) -> int:
        morse = [".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."]
        alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
        transformation = []
        zip_ = list(zip(morse, alphabet))
        for word in words:
            transformation.append(''.join(code[0] for code in zip_ for letter in word if letter in code[1]))
```

output:

```
['--...-.', '.-.--..', '--.--...', '--.--...']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you first iterate through the zip_, and then through the letters. That's what is causing the alphabetical order -- zip_ is alphabetically sorted.

This version does what you want it to do:

```
 class Solution: 
      def uniqueMorseRepresentations(self, words: List[str]) -> int: 
          morse = [".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."] 
          alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] 
          transformation = [] 
          zip_ = list(zip(morse, alphabet)) 
          for word in words: 
              transformation.append(''.join(code[0] for letter in word for code in zip_  if letter in code[1]))
```

It is not the most Pythonic way of doing it, but it is the smallest fix to your solution.

Personally, I would use a dictionary mapping letters to Morse code, and then iterate through the characters of the string. This is kind of similar to https://stackoverflow.com/users/6553328/emma 's solution, but a bit easier to read for people who don't know the integer values of chars.

Comment: Very good answer, just a small remark: I believe your answer will be much clearer and more concise if you just post the single line of code that was changed. As the change is actually very minor, it gets obscured with the rest of the code and makes it hard to find the actual fix...

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the problem that you're facing, this'll pass though:

```
class Solution:
    def uniqueMorseRepresentations(self, words):
        morse_map = [".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--",
             "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."]
        return len({''.join(morse_map[ord(char) - 97] for char in word) for word in words})
```

97 is `ord('a')`:

```
class Solution:
    def uniqueMorseRepresentations(self, words):
        morse_map = [".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--",
             "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."]
        return len({''.join(morse_map[ord(char) - ord('a')] for char in word) for word in words})
```

I don't see a `return` statement or a `set()` in your solution. There are two simple steps:

- Add visited transformations into a set
- Return the length of the set

---

Here is also a Java version using a HashSet (similar to the `set()` in Python), if you'd be interested:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final int uniqueMorseRepresentations(
        final String[] words
    ) {
        final String[] morseMap = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};
        Set<String> transformations = new HashSet<>();

        for (String word : words) {
            StringBuilder transformation = new StringBuilder();

            for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++)
                transformation.append(morseMap[word.charAt(index) - 97]);

            transformations.add(transformation.toString());
        }

        return transformations.size();
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-morse-code-words/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.